# npm v9.4.0 does not support Node.js v14.15.0

Tags: node.js, npm

What is accept version `npm` for (`Node.js v14.15.0`). Get me bellow error:

```
npm WARN cli npm v9.4.0 does not support Node.js v14.
15.0. You should probably upgrade to a
npm WARN cli newer version of node as we can't make any promises that npm will work with this
npm WARN cli version. This version of npm supports the following node versions: `^14.17.0 ||
npm WARN cli ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0`. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.
```

NOTICE: I don't need to change version of (`Node.js v14.15.0`) I need to accept version `npm` for (`Node.js v14.15.0`).

Comment: You can find your Node.js version, and the NPM version that came with it, here: https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

Comment: If you search v14.15.0 in this url you can't find any v14.15.0. I saw it.  :-|

Comment: Just scroll through the table, it's there.